# (Multipart) zip upload in ruby webmachine handled by rack

Tags: ruby, rack, webmachine

I'm making an upload form for zips in a ruby webmachine app. My idea is to have an upload through my backend where I can add some extra params and then upload it to amazons s3 service with RestClient.

I did successfully create a direct upload (web based form post) to a s3bucket, but in that way I'm unable to handle the variables which are needed in the request, the way I want.

I've tried several things but I can't figure out, how to handle the request, as soon as it gets in my backend. I've created a resource and I'm debugging directly in the `process_post` method.

My `@request` variable represents a `Webmachine::Request`, with a `Webmachine::Adapters::Rack::RequestBody` and a `Rack::Request`, but I can't get the file out of it to use it as input for my RestClient request.

I think; `@request.body.to_s` and `@request.body.to_io`, represent the uploaded file in some way, and I tried to use them as input for `Rack::Multipart` methods, but that doesn't give me the file.

I also tried to work with the rack-raw-upload gem, but I can't get the mime-type something else than "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or multipart. I do explicitly set it to; `application/octet-stream`

Things like `File.new(filename, 'rb')` gave me `rrno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen'. For filename I just used 'example.zip'.

I guess I'm missing something which has to do with the Rack::Request call(env) method.

Does somebody have an idea, on how to handle the Rack uploads? Or give me any hints for a new direction? Thanks.

Comment: Might be worth posting your Rack code.

Comment: @tadman Well, I don't have actual rack code. I just know that Rack handles the file uploads. And the Rack code that I tried, is above; the `Rack::Multipart` methods, like `parse_multipart`. Should I have implemented other Rack code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a gist which shows how to retrieve the multipart stream. You'll need further parsing in order to get the uploaded file.

https://gist.github.com/jewilmeer/eb40abd665b70f53e6eb60801de24342

Comment: Thanks. The `File.write` part pushed me in the right direction. And I found out that `request.body.to_s` could do the trick too, instead of `request.body.to_io.read`.